# Data generating for the functional regression problem

Tags: r, regression, data-generation

Have a problem with data generating and I have no idea how to solve this. All information provided in photo: [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duf1F.png).

I think that X_i(t) in both cases should be 200 x 100 if we say that t is from 0 to 1 (length = 100). Furthermore, coefficients for polynomial should contain 200 x 4 and coefficients for fourier should contain 200 x 5. Bu I have no idea how to start to solve this problem.

Here is some code. So, I have already defined my beta's, but I can't defeat generating of X_i(t).

```r
t <- seq(0, 1, length = 100)

beta_1t <- rep(0, 100)
plot(t, beta_1t, type = "l")

beta_2t <- (t >= 0 & t < 0.342) * ((t - 0.5)^2 - 0.025) +
      (t >= 0.342 & t <= 0.658) * 0 +
      (t > 0.658 & t <= 1) * (-(t - 0.5)^2 + 0.025)
plot(t, beta_2t, type = "l")

beta_3t <- t^3 - 1.6 * t^2 + 0.76 * t  + 1
plot(t, beta_3t, type = "l")

poly_c <- matrix(rnorm(n = 800, mean = 0, sd = 1), ncol = 4)
four_c <- matrix(rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1), ncol = 5)
```

As I mentioned before, there should be (X_i(t), Y_i(t)) samples. Here i = 1, 2, ..., 200; t from [0, 1] (length = 100).

Comment: Maybe add the programming language as a tag? I guess R?

Comment: Yeah, it's R. I added language as a tag.